# How to fix acidic smell from fridge/freezer?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

Started to smell a bad acidic smell coming from the bottom of my fridge.
This is the model: https://mcappliance.com/brands/magic-chef/4-5-cu-ft-compact-refrigerator-665679004973.html

Tried the cleaning methods of inside the fridge, baking soda etc.

I believe the cause is this strange flaked copper buildup on top of the motor.
I have no idea what this is or how to safely clean it.
The manual doesn't provide any knowledge about this part.
There doesn't appear to be any leaks.

[image]
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For clarity, it is buildup of stuff from somewhere else and not flaking or failure of the paint or other item that is already there?

Comment: hi @Ack. It certainly appears to be from somewhere else. The buildup is in the top tray part (1st picture) which is just a black plastic tray. The buildup is flaky with it becoming sticky and condense towards the extreme right of the tray. I have not observed any paint or stripping from the areas around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tray under your refrigerator is there to catch condensation is it goes through its normal operating cycles.

The water might building up and overflowing or other there is direct condensation in the other areas. The color and smell is from the typical things that grow in stagnant water (mold, etc) and can be cleaned up with the same normal cleaners. It probably got a foothold in the tray, and if the tray is not overflowing, then also got to the other wet locations easily from the tray colony.

This is then a typical household cleaning issue that you can approach as normal.

Things you can do to improve the situation: some water in the tray is normal so it's not an option to not have water there but we can make it unfriendly to the little buggies: put a few drops of chlorine bleach in the tray once in a while to keep it non-life supporting. Since there is an issue outside the tray, this indicates that your house might have a lot of moisture. If so, a (portable) dehumidifier can bring down the humidity to something more reasonable

Comment: Thank you @Ack for your detailed answer. Should unplugging the appliance be enough of a precaution to cleaning it out?

Comment: You are very welcome. Yes, just unplugging is enough. It does not have capacitors which store energy (that is literally what they are there for) after the power is unplugged and can you harm if touched. You are good to go